# python reindex doesn't show column values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm working with python 3.7 and pandas in JupyterLab and trying to use reindex to add missing rows in a MultiIndex table (index should be a product with the elements from Col1 and Col2).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11,],
                   'Col2': ['2012', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2012'],
                   'result': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

start, end = df2['Col1'].min(), df2['Col1'].max()
Col2_values = df2['Col2'].sort_values().unique()
newIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [range(start, end+1), Col2_values ], names=['Col1', 'Col2'],)
 
df2 = df2.reindex( newIndex, columns=['result'] )
print(df2)
```

What it shows is:

```
           result
Col1 Col2        
10   2012     NaN
     2013     NaN
```

Could anybody tell me how I can preserve the values of the column result?

Comment: I guess last year is `2016`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex` from `col1` and `col2` for `reindex` by `MultiIndex`, else `reindex` use default `RangeIndex` (`0-6`), no value match and get all `NaN`s is output column:

```
#last year is 2016
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11,],
                   'Col2': ['2012', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
                   'result': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

start, end = df2['Col1'].min(), df2['Col1'].max()
Col2_values = df2['Col2'].sort_values().unique()
newIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product( [range(start, end+1), Col2_values ], 
                                       names=['Col1', 'Col2'],)
print (newIndex) 
MultiIndex([(10, '2012'),
            (10, '2013'),
            (10, '2014'),
            (10, '2015'),
            (10, '2016'),
            (11, '2012'),
            (11, '2013'),
            (11, '2014'),
            (11, '2015'),
            (11, '2016'),
            (12, '2012'),
            (12, '2013'),
            (12, '2014'),
            (12, '2015'),
            (12, '2016')],
           names=['Col1', 'Col2'])
```

---

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['Col1','Col2']).reindex( newIndex, columns=['result'] )
print(df2)
           result
Col1 Col2        
10   2012     1.0
     2013     NaN
     2014     NaN
     2015     NaN
     2016     NaN
11   2012     1.0
     2013     NaN
     2014     NaN
     2015     NaN
     2016     1.0
12   2012     NaN
     2013     1.0
     2014     1.0
     2015     1.0
     2016     NaN
```

Comment: Perfect. It's working now. Got often 'cannot handle a non-unique multi-index' and doesn't looked a the mistyped value.

Comment: @Dan - So it means there are duplicated values, need instead `df2.set_index(['Col1','Col2'])` aggregate, e.g. by `mean` like `df2.groupby(['Col1','Col2']).mean()`